# "Open Implementation" in Eclipse CDT

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

From within Eclipse CDT (Juno), how can I quickly navigate to a the implementation(s) of a function/method declaration?

The `ctrl-click` keyboard shortcut allows me to navigate from the implementation (in a `.cxx` file) to the declaration (`.h` file). I want the opposite behavior.

Answer (score 5):

I Use <kbd>F3</kbd> when the text is on the function, this alternates between declaration and implementation.

Answer (score 2):

The <kbd>ctrl-click</kbd> in the header file moves you to a source (implementation) file and vice-versa.

P.S. I test it on Juno SR1.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, one may jump from declaration (`.h`) to definition (`.cpp`) and backwards, using context menu item `Toggle Source/Header` (given the method/function highlighted).

This also helped me fix the initial <kbd>F3</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + click's incorrect behavior, which pressure forwarded only and uniquely to method declaration.